# How to create Azure Virtual machine with VM Extension using the python SDK

Tags: python, azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-python

I want to create an Azure virtual machine with the VM extension(Custom script extension) using the python SDK. Basically, I want a python program that will create the VM with VM extension using the Azure SDK management libraries, I am able to use the Azure SDK management libraries in a Python script to create a resource group that contains a Linux virtual machine.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-virtual-machines?tabs=cmd

But I need my Virtual machine with VM extension in it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, we don't have proper documentation related to the creation of VM with extension.

- Here is the [SDK reference document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_07_01.operations.virtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-python) for creating and updating the extension

  VirtualMachineExtensionsOperations(client, config, serializer, deserializer)
- Here is the sample code to create the extension

  begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name: str, vm_name: str, vm_extension_name: str, extension_parameters: "_models.VirtualMachineExtension", **kwargs: Any) -> LROPoller['_models.VirtualMachineExtension']
- Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python?source=docs#feedback) for creation Virtual machine using python.

Comment: Hi @SaiSakethGuduru-MT, do we have to run it with the begin_create_or_update() for creating the instance or after the instance is created? That is do we add it as a parameter to the function call to create an instance?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what to add.  extension_parameters is listed as required, so I am not sure what to put.  What do we put for AADLoginForLinux extension?

Answer (score 0):

```
compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_create_or_update(
RUNNER_RG,
resource_name_and_IP,
{
    "location": "eastus",
    "storage_profile": {
        "image_reference": {
            "id": image_id
        }
    },
    "hardware_profile": {
        "vm_size": "Standard_F8s_v2"
    },
    "os_profile": {
        "computer_name": resource_name_and_IP,
        "admin_username": "azuser",
        "linux_configuration": {
            "disable_password_authentication": True,
            "ssh": {
                "public_keys": [
                    {
                        "path": "/home/azuser/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                        # Add the public key for a key pair that can get access to SSH to the runners
                        "key_data": "ssh public key here"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "network_profile": {
        "network_interfaces": [
            {
                "id": nic_result.id,
                "properties": {"deleteOption": "Delete"}
            }
        ]
    },
    "identity": params_identity,
    "vm_azure_extension": "AADSSHLogin"
})
```

Just adding vm_azure_extension did not add the extension.